# Exclude file names with pattern from PyCharm search

Tags: pycharm, filenames

I have a large number of auto generated code files that are identifiable by the having _pb2 in the file name.

When I search using PyCharm <kbd>CTRL+Shift+F</kbd> I can use a file mask. I would like for instance to find all Python files `*.py` that do not have `_pb2` in their name. Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can include and exclude files and directories by creating a Custom Scope that filters using a combination of filename wildcards.

1. <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+F</kbd> to open *"Find in Path"*.
2. Create a new Custom Scope following steps 2-4 in the screenshot.

[image]

5. Enter the pattern,  for your specification it would be `file[Project_Name]:*.py&&!file:*_pb2*`
6. Afterwards the search results are restricted to within the Custom Scope.

[image]

Source at JetBrains official site: [*"Scope configuration controls"*](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-scopes.html#options)